# What's the best approach to storing User Notifications in Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

New to Parse backend and coding all together...

Developing my first iOS app and I'm contemplating how I should store the data in Parse.

So I want to get advice from you lovely, experienced developers. What's the best way to structure my Parse class(es) if I want to store comments, follow requests, favorites, etc. That would make it simple when querying in an Alert tab within my app.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to store all the alerts on parse but rather send one alert via a notification and it's payload and store it locally.